# How can i reference an Android Project from another project using ANT

Tags: android, ant

I have 2 projects say P1 & P2, 
P2 refers to P1.

When i create my projects using eclipse, I am able to reference P1 from P2 by simply adding it to 
P2->Properties->Java Build Path->Projects. And it compiles and runs fine.

Now am trying to build the project using ANT, 
but i am not able to find out how to add reference to P1 in P2.

The only way that i found was addign "android.library.reference" point to P1. But as P1 is not a library but an android application this is not working.

How can i add the project reference of P1 into P2??
As this is working fine from eclipse, i am sure there should be a way to do it with ANT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit strange to use P1 as a library if it is not.

But if you want to call P1 build.xml, simply use a call to antcall : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html. 
Thus you can compile P1 prior to P2.

If you want P1 classes to be usable in P2, add the source or resulting P1 jar file to P2 classpath compile target.

I must say that android tools change quite often and quite a lot and the ant script change more often than the rest. Consequently, I would encourage you to have a more standard build, it's gonna be already difficult enough to maintain it : turn P1 into a library.

A good alternative to get your build process decoupled from google tool changes is to use maven and the [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/). It's more cutting edge, relies on maven for dependencies and will provide an easier move toward continous IC on jenkins.

Comment: _(If you want P1 classes to be usable in P2, add the source or resulting P1 jar file to P2 classpath compile target.)_
Sorry i am a bit new here, Can you let me know how to do this using Ant